# copying header of a csv file into another csv file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a script of my own wherein I want to include a command that would copy header of a csv file into a new csv file. I don't know how to accomplish this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files can contains elements, that contains linefeeds. In this case, the first logical CSV line is spread over 2 ore more physical lines. So physical line based tools like head, tail, grep awk or sed can't be used.

Example for a 1 line CSV line with 2 columns:

```
"first
column","second
column"
```

You have to use tools that support CSV analysis like `python` or `php`. Here is a php example:

```
 php -r 'fputcsv(STDOUT,fgetcsv(STDIN));'
```

It reads from stdin and writes the first logic line to stdout.

Usage examples:

```
php -r 'fputcsv(STDOUT,fgetcsv(STDIN));' <old.csv >new.csv
any_command | php -r 'fputcsv(STDOUT,fgetcsv(STDIN));' >new.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ head -1 old.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: This copies the first line of the file, but not always the first logical line of a CSV file. It fails, if an element contains a linefeed.

Comment: If an element contains a linefeed, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Why? I process CSV files with elements with line feeds without problems.